# DNS servers not set properly? Site failing to load by hostname, though loads fine by IP

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-server

We run www.tekiki.com. Some users, including us, cannot reach www.tekiki.com because of DNS issues. The site resolves fine on the desktop, but it fails from our iPhones and iPads. The frustrating thing is this isn't doesn't happen to everyone. We noticed the problem yesterday, then set our DNS servers to Cloudflare's DNS servers, hoping that would fix things.

Typing in the IP addr directly loads the site fine.

Two questions:

1) Does anyone know what the solution is?

2) Should we use other DNS servers besides Cloudflare?

Comment: Have you contacted CloudFlare support to ask why their servers aren't answering DNS queries for your domain?

Answer (score 2):

Your DNS servers (`gina.ns.cloudflare.com` & `max.ns.cloudflare.com`) are both returning `SERVFAIL` -- something is wrong with the `tekiki.com` zone, or the servers.
We can't tell you any more without some effort on your end (log files from the DNS server would be a good starting point, though I doubt cloudflare will give you those).

---

> 1) Does anyone know what the solution is?

*Fix your DNS*.

---

> 2) Should we use other DNS servers besides Cloudflare?

You should *fix your DNS*. If Cloudflare is your DNS provider you should contact Cloudflare for help troubleshooting the problem.

Comment: Thanks! How do we fix our DNS aside from specifying different DNS servers for our domain? We'll reach out to Cloudflare now.

Comment: @Crashalot We don't know how your domain is broken. That's between you and Cloudflare. You are the second person I'm going to *strongly* urge to purchase [The Cricket Book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596100575.do) though, as it will be helpful to you in the future if you have to troubleshoot DNS issues.

Comment: Thanks! We have the issue resolved now, but do you recommend someone else besides CloudFlare to set as our DNS servers?